# SharePoint Rest Service sorting is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to add the sorting on SharePoint list using Rest services but it is not working.

I am adding sorting on the basis of particular columns(Description, Col_Order), columns have values 1,2.

If the Col_Order have entered the numeric values then it should sorted in ascending order. If not then sorting should be on the basis of Description columns. But the sorting is not get work.

I am adding like in below:

```
http://dev.listdata.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/WasteCodes?$orderby=(Col_Order%20eq%20null),%20Description%20
```

Comment: Is `WasteCodes` is display name of your list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes. In this list have the Description and Col_Order columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below REST Query:

```
http://dev.listdata.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/WasteCodes?$select=Col_Order,Description&$orderby=Col_Order asc,Description
```

**Or** try using something like below REST API:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$orderby=Col_Order asc,Description
```

**Reference**:

[Using the REST Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff798339(v=pandp.10)).

Comment: It's not showing results correctly.

Comment: This query will order your list items in ascending order by Col_Order and then by Description

Comment: You got the logic but it sort the list by Description

Comment: In Second URL, if the Col_Order is null then the result will always come at top order.

Comment: Second URL showing the same way list is showing sorting by Description.

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier, firstly list items will be ordered by Col_Order in ascending order(if the Col_Order is null then the result will always come at top order) and then the results will be ordered by Description column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96956/discussion-between-ganesh-sanap-and-mobile-test).